# trigger problems on sql

Tags: sql, function, triggers

need to run a trigger that updated a column in my customers table. the idea is that once the customers table is updated the trigger needs to update a different column with a scalar. the scalar is calculated by a function.
I don't know where is the issue but something is going very wrong.

```
create FUNCTION calculateVirtualCashForCustomer(@email varchar) 
RETURNS float
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @virtualCashToAdd float
    select  @virtualCashToAdd= (B.Price*(cast(O.Quantity as float)))*0.1
    from CUSTOMERS AS C JOIN BOXES AS B ON C.Email = B.Email JOIN ORDERS AS O ON O.BoxID = B.BoxID  
    where C.Email = @email
    RETURN  @virtualCashToAdd
End



CREATE TRIGGER updateVirtualCash
    on CUSTOMERS
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
    DECLARE @Mail varchar(50)
    begin
    update CUSTOMERS
    set [Virtual Cash] = [Virtual Cash] + (dbo.calculateVirtualCashForCustomer(@Mail))
    where  @Mail= (select Email from dbo.Top10byMoney)
end
```

Comment: This is the issue: [The Silent Bug I Find in Most Triggers](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)

Comment: Hi welcome on stackoverflow. Please add more clarity to your question. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is in `where  @Mail= (select Email from dbo.Top10byMoney)` of the trigger. you can try add `top 1` in `select`, so to compare only with a selected value

Example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateVirtualCash
    on CUSTOMERS
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS
    DECLARE @Mail varchar(50)
    SET @Mail= (select Email from dbo.Top10byMoney)
    begin
    update CUSTOMERS
    set [Virtual Cash] = [Virtual Cash] + (dbo.calculateVirtualCashForCustomer(@Mail))
    where  Email=@Mail
end
```

for solve the values null problem, you can use ISNULL

```
set [Virtual Cash] = ISNULL([Virtual Cash],0) + ISNULL(dbo.calculateVirtualCashForCustomer(@Mail),0)
```

Comment: looks like it solved the issue thx! however it throws this error : Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'virtual Cash', table 'ourproject.dbo.customers'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: check if calculateVirtualCashForCustomer return is not null

Comment: in the addition use ISNULL for avoid values null.

Comment: indeed the function returns null. im trying to debugg it but just cant figure out why.

Comment: just escaping the null error isnt gonna work for me cause I need to solve this..I believe it's somewhere between the declaration of the local variable to the return statement..lol we are 3 tired students sitting on this shit via zoom for the last 4 hours blessed be the one who redeems us

Comment: i think that is because not find the Email in the function. try initialize @Mail after of be declared. check the answer I have already edited it